# Is it possible to set the "spans" attribute of a row in the "worksheet#.xml" using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, xssf

this is a "worksheet#.xml" inside a .xlsx file I created with MS Office Excel.

```
<worksheet mc:Ignorable="x14ac" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac">
    ...
        <sheetViews>
            <sheetView tabSelected="1" workbookViewId="0">
                <selection activeCell="B27" sqref="B27"/>
            </sheetView>
        </sheetViews>
        <sheetFormatPr baseColWidth="10" defaultRowHeight="12.75" x14ac:dyDescent="0.2"/>
        <cols>
            <col min="1" max="1" customWidth="true" width="17.28515625" collapsed="false"/>
            <col min="2" max="2" customWidth="true" width="156.5703125" collapsed="false"/>
            <col min="3" max="3" customWidth="true" width="11.42578125" collapsed="false"/>
        </cols>
        <sheetData>
            <row r="1" spans="1:2" x14ac:dyDescent="0.2">
                <c r="A1" s="5" t="s">
                    <v>43</v>
                </c><c r="B1" s="1" t="s">
                    <v>44</v>
                </c>
            </row>
            <row r="2" spans="1:2" x14ac:dyDescent="0.2">
                <c r="A2" s="6" t="s">
                    <v>45</v>
                </c><c r="B2" s="2" t="s">
                    <v>46</v>
                </c>
            </row>
        </sheetData>
    ...
    </worksheet>
```

If I append rows to this file using Apache POI, I get additional rows without any spans or formats

```
...
<row r="#">
   ...
</row>
...
```

Is there a way to set the span of a row using Apache POI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create merged cells the following way:

```
CellRangeAddress region = CellRangeAddress.valueOf("B2:E5");
sheet1.addMergedRegion( region );
```